# React native custom navbar setState avoid rendering all

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a custom navbar component using react native router flux :

```
 render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.navBar}>
            {this._renderNavBarLeft() }
            {this._renderNavBarMiddle() }
            {this._renderNavBarRight() }
        </View>

    )
}
```

with render middle part:

```
 _renderNavBarMiddle() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.navBarItem}>
            { this.state.timeElapsed ? (<Text style={styles.text}>{Moment.utc(this.state.timeElapsed).format('HH:mm:ss')}</Text>) : <Text style={styles.text}>00:00:00</Text>}
        </View>
    )
}
```

and i have a backgroundTimer to refresh middle navbar part

```
   componentDidMount(){
    console.warn("mount")
    const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
            timeElapsed : new Date() - this.state.startTime,
        })
    },1000)
}
```

how can i avoid  {this._renderNavBarLeft() } and   {this._renderNavBarRight() } being render each time setState (timeElapsed ) was called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to include

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // return false, if component should not update 
    return false;
}
```

to your left and right navbar components. Probably you need to pass additonal props, to avoid re-rendering.

Comment: thanks, so i have no choice to create two component left and right ? :/